# Writing data to HBase

Tags: java, web-crawler, row, hbase, nutch

I'm using Nutch to crawl site data and then writing data to HBase. Problem is that, in tutorials is mentioned, how to update the specific row (put), but not how to create with Java code. How to create row at crawling time, that "row number" will increment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got idea. If someone is interested: Use any unique value of data as "key". For example, I have to work with books, so my row "number" will be unique ISBN code.